# PHP com atualizações em tempo real

Tags: php

Quero começar um projeto, e estudando e fazendo levantamentos vi a necessidade de atualização em tempo real. Como por exemplo:

Tenho uma tela de ligação, onde mostra as empresas para as quais as telemarketing's tem que ligar. Suponhamos que a mesma empresa apareça para as duas telemarketing's na mesma tela ou na mesma listagem, quando a primeira telemarketing clicar nessa empresa, essa empresa tem que sumir da tela da outra automaticamente.

Realmente teria que ser uma atualização em tempo real, já pesquisei e não achei muita coisa relevante.

Queria saber de vocês se o PHP tem suporte para isso, e se alguém já passou por algo parecido e como solucionou. Feedbacks de como fazer isso são aceitos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atualmente, a maneira mais recomendável de fazer isso, seria utilizando [WebSockets](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), para uma conexão cliente-servidor permanente.

Infelizmente, os WebSockets ainda não são vastamente suportados por todos os browsers (basicamente, só Chrome e as últimas versões dos outros navegadores). Então, existem alternativas, como o [Long Pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), que usei em um projeto recentemente.

Long Pooling consiste, basicamente, em ficar "perguntando" pro servidor, a intervalos regulares, se existe alguma informação nova, como no exemplo:

```
(function poll(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //aqui você faz seu código...


        //prepara o próximo poll recursivamente
        poll();
      }, dataType: "json"});
  }, 30000);
})();
```

A função acima, contata o servidor regularmente (a cada 30 segundos), para pedir informações.

Você pode procurar por ferramentas que encapsulem as técnicas existentes desse tipo de tecnologia, que disponibilizem para você a mais adequada, de acordo com o navegador. Não conheço ferramentas assim para desenvolver em PHP, mas para ASP.NET, existe o [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: Entendi.. Vou analisar . O motivo de querer fazer em php é porque tenho pouco tempo , e aprender outra linguagem vai ser difícil.

Comment: É perfeitamente possível fazer em PHP. PHP está no mesmo patamar que C#, e foi em C# que eu fiz o meu projeto

Comment: Essa comentário me tranquilizou um pouco rsrs.. Estou pensando em usar o Long Pooling ou WebSockets, mas como vc disse WebSockets não tem muito suporte. Seria uma boa eu obrigar os usuarios a usarem um navegador mais atualizado ? Levando em conta que esse produto teoricamente não seria muito popular rsrs. Mas vou analisando!

Comment: Alguns sites recomendam a utilização de software mais atualizado para "melhor experiência". Mas você não deve obrigar o usuário a usar algo, é uma prática ruim. Você pode implementar o LongPooling simples, como esse que eu exemplifiquei, e em um futuro distante, trocar a tecnologia, caso queira.

Comment: É verdade. Mas a qual a diferença de performance entre LongPooling e WebSockets ?

Comment: Web Sockets você mantém a conexão cliente-servidor aberta permanentemente, podendo fazer com que informação trafegue nos dois lados. Nas outras técnicas, ou você mantém um loop infinito na requisição, para aumentar o tempo dela e fazê-la esperar (Long Pooling), ou você fica perguntando esporadicamente por informação, como esse exemplo que te dei. Mas não sei dizer qual é a diferença em questão de performance, porém acho que WebSockets tem vantagem, visto que não precisa ficar fazendo requests